# Angular 2 ngIf and NgFor breaks up when having multiple columns of data

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, ng-container

I have an angular 2 code, where I am using *ngFor to loop within some package and then I am using ngIf for table header and then display values accordingly. The problem is when the table is having only one package, it works perfectly fine. when I have more than one packages, that point of time the code breaks up. When package is having only one column of data it works fine , but when it has multiple data means multiple columns that time the the click function - "Elect all and Unselect all" stops working. can someone guide what might be the issue in the code below.

*Angular*

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pack of myobj.packages">
   <th *ngIf="myobj.type != 'A' && myobj.type != 'B'">
       {{pack.name}} 
   </th>
   <th *ngIf="(myobj.type!= 'A' && myobj.type != 'B') && myobj.electable">
       <span>
          <a (click)="myfn()">Elect All</a>
          <span *ngIf="myobj.type!='O'">|<a (click)="myfn()">Unelect All</a>
          </span>
       </span>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let pack of myobj.packages">
           <th *ngIf="myobj.type=='B' || myobj.type=='A'">
               {{pack.name}} 
           </th>
       </ng-container>
   </th>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: <th> within <th>, I don't think that's valid html

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have been checking wrong value and having duplicate array name:

"let pack of myobj.packages"

if your array myobj.packages has properties like 'type', 'name', 'electable' then try the below code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pack of myobj.packages">
   <th *ngIf="pack.type != 'A' && pack.type != 'B'">
       {{pack.name}} 
   </th>
   <th *ngIf="(pack.type!= 'A' && pack.type != 'B') && pack.electable">
       <span>
          <a (click)="myfn()">Elect All</a>
          <span *ngIf="pack.type!='O'">|<a (click)="myfn()">Unelect All</a>
          </span>
       </span>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let pack1 of myobj.packages">
           <th *ngIf="pack1.type=='B' || pack1.type=='A'">
               {{pack1.name}} 
           </th>
       </ng-container>
   </th>
</ng-container>
```